# PHP - Getting next thursday's date

Tags: php, datetime

**Code**

```
$order_dispatch_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $inc['order_dispatch_date']);
$order_dispatch_date = $order_dispatch_date->format('Ymd');

$order_collection = date('Ymd', strtotime('next thursday', $order_dispatch_date));

$order_collection = new DateTime($order_collection); 

echo '['.$order_collection->format('d/m/Y') . ' - ' . $order_dispatch_date . ' - ' . gettype($order_dispatch_date) . ' ] ';
```

I get the following output if the input is: `20171128`

```
[29/08/1970 - 20171128 - string ]
```

My question is why is the first output showing 29th August 1970 rather than 20th November 2017?

Comment: If you are getting 1970 dates, it just means the date was invalid to begin with.. strtotime takes a timestamp as a 2nd parameter, not the date string.. so add strtotime() around that as well and it should work.

Comment: Why not just `$d = new DateTime('next Thursday')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

```
$order_collection = date('Ymd', strtotime('next thursday', strtotime($order_dispatch_date)));
```

And that should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Stop changing things back-and-forth between objects, strings and timestamps so much, especially when you're re-using the same variables. It's needlessly hard to follow.

If you've got a `Ymd` formatted string, and you want an equivalent string back for the proceeding Thursday, just use this:

```
$inc['order_dispatch_date'] = '20171128';

$order_dispatch_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $inc['order_dispatch_date'])->modify('next thursday');

echo $order_dispatch_date->format('Ymd');
// 20171130
```

See https://eval.in/909998